# Prove $ |\langle u,v\rangle| = \lVert u \rVert \cdot \lVert v \rVert$

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

If V is the finite dimensional inner product space, then prove the following:

If $u, v \in V$ are linearly dependent, then $  |\langle u,v\rangle| = \lVert u \rVert \cdot \lVert v \rVert$

Thanks.

Comment: @SimonS I tried to prove like proving "Schwarz's Inequality" but I'm pretty sure its wrong.

Comment: $u, v$ are linearly *dependent* if there exists non-zero constants $a, b$ such that $au + bv = 0$. Hence we can write $u = kv$ where $k = -b/a$. Use that to evaluate the left-hand and the right-hand sides of your expression. E.g.,

$$|\langle u, v \rangle| = |\langle kv, v \rangle| = \ \cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to prove that if $u,v$ are linearly dependent, then there exists $\alpha$ such that $v = \alpha u$.

Comment: Something like this: $<u,v> = <cv,v> = |c|<v,v> = |c| ||v|| = |c| ||v|| ||v|| = ||cv|| ||v|| = ||u|| ||v||$ ??

Answer (score 2):

If they are linearly dependent then $u = cv$ for some constant $c$. Then you have that $|\langle u, v \rangle| = |c|\cdot ||v||^2$.  Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong: $<u,v> = <cv,v> = |c|<v,v> = |c| ||v|| = |c| ||v|| ||v|| = ||cv|| ||v|| = ||u|| ||v||$ ??

Comment: @rndflas Yes, your computation is exactly what I was getting at.